# Extend internally used PHP class without changing dependencies

Tags: php, laravel, overriding, extends

I want to override a PHP class in Laravel, however it is being extended upon by several other classes which I don't want to disturb. The general structure looks like so

```php
class A extends R { }
class B extends R { }
class C extends R { }
class D extends R { }
```

where A/B/C/D/R are all classes from the external package.

I want to extend A/B/C/D to `P` without changing any of those files (which would be a maintenance burden), such that `class P extends R`. I can thus make my additions to class `P`.

I've been looking at [`class_alias()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php) which allows me to hook into the autoloader. This loads class `P` correctly.

The code I am using is:

```php
// Some bootstrap file:
class_alias(
    P::class,
    R::class
);
```

```php
// My modification:
class P extends R
{
    // ...
}
```

However I run into the error:

> ErrorException: Cannot declare class `R`, because the name is already in use

I am looking for a solution where I can extend an internal PHP class while preventing copying the complete file contents of a class. I don't even know if it can be done. The class I want to extend is not adapted to the Laravel service container so there is no first-party method to add functionality.

Comment: Switch places R with P in your `class_alias` function. Initial class is R and P is an alias for R as far as i understand, or am i wrong ) Actually you can extend directly from R without doing alias shenanigans and redefine whatever you need. Regarding `__clone()` prevention of the class. Either make it `private function __clone()` or simply throw an `exception` inside of the `__clone` method.

Comment: Nothing happens when I call it the other way around (the default class is loaded) which is what i initially tried. I don't see the connection with `__clone()` here though?

Comment: [Object Cloning\Copy](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) in terms of php it does related to what you have asked. In term's of laravel i do not see an issue to do what you wanted to do and hide it behind the `facade` and call it with some sort of `accessor`(to hide your complex horizontal scaling of classes). But actually in term's of SOLID it's better to start from `interfaces`

Comment: I think I've miscommunicated the sentence "full-class copies" in the question. I have changed it to "copying the complete file contents of a class" (there is no __clone restriction requirement)

Answer (score 0):

class_alias on its own is not enough for this, because in order for P to extend R, both classes have to exist. And class_alias isn't related to autoloading, it's just declaring a class with two names.

What you actually need is to define the real class R with a new name, and then define your own class with the name R (you don't actually need class_alias for that).

One way to do this would be to dynamically rewrite the source code of the target class, and then load the modified copy, something like this (untested):

```
$code = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/vendor/path/to/R.php');
$code = str_replace('class R', 'class R_original', $code);
eval($code);

class R extends R_original {
   // Your code here
}
```

The important thing is that this needs to run *before* the normal autoloader tries to define the class. For instance, you could register a custom autoloader to come before Composer's generated one using [`spl_autoload_register` with the `$prepend` option set to true](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php).